# Which the best way to start spiritual journey?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, yoga, tantra

I want to know the best way to start my spiritual journey? Could someone suggest any type of Dhyana or meditation?

Comment: First you need to find Guru Diksha from an able Guru. That is the first step in spiritual progress.

Comment: @Rickross I thought about that too, Some days ago I go on a trip to kolkata where I go to kalighata temple which is one of the shakti peeths I thought that maybe there I would be able to find a guru since there were so many pandits but only thing I found there was bas**rds trying to earn money on the name of God you can't even offer Prasad there without giving money to them, also I've at many places that I can't find a guru only my guru can find me, what am I supposed to do till then

Comment: Temples might not be the correct place for getting Guru .. you should approach Belur Math or RK Math .. they initiate depending on certain conditions. But you should approach them first for Diksha and see how they respond.

Comment: @Abhinav Raj Sir are u only interested in the Agama-Tantra path or are u also interested in the Vedanta path?

Comment: @Rickross I go there but for only an hour bcz I don't live in kolkata I only go there for a trip

Comment: @Rāmachandra I've no problem in following any path

Comment: For Starters then read some low level introductory books on hinduism
'A primer of Hinduism' by D. S. Sharma(beginner lvl); 'Essentials of Hinduism' by Swami Bhaskarananda; and An advanced level beginner text  'The Spiritual Heritage of India' by Swami Prabhavananda(explanation of all the different sects, their philosophies, what the different scriptures are and the relationship of the different scriptures to each other. It explains who the different past exponents of the different systems are).
Also 'Hindu Gods and Goddesses' by Swami Harshananda.(personally read all of these)

Comment: Above texts are quoted from this beautiful ans by Pradip Gangopadhayay Ji :-https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16692/a-comprehensive-book-on-hinduism
You can also go through other introductory texts mentioned by him.Right now your goal should not be whining but trying to make yourself worthy of a Guru, because only the luckiest people have the chance to be near the lotus feet of his Guru at a young age.When you are ready and ripe enough for initiation, through God's grace you would be surely guided towards your Guru!

Comment: @Abhinav Raj - you ought not to call them 'bas**rds', that money is demanded by WB Government, and they have no choice in that matter. If you want to call that, call WB Govt. (and federal govt which is not changing that archaic law) bas**rds.

Comment: Try to contact them through email about Diksha .. try to contact the RK Mission that is nearest to the place where you stay .. might be one center is there in your city only? @AbhinavRaj

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, one should go for first reading theory given by maharishi patanjali. It is know by name "ashtanga yoga". He lays down step by step process on how to attain higher states of oneself. Meditation is the last step in his process.

One of the book, which I read and really liked it because of its scientific and practical approach is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raja_Yoga_(book)

For overview on ashtanga yoga, please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtanga_(eight_limbs_of_yoga)

Note, I am not saying that other types of yoga are not effective but only expressing my views/experience that ashtanga yoga is very effective in today's world because it starts from gross and move to subtle higher planes. To know different kinds of yogas  and choose which is best according to your nature, you can read bhagwat geeta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita

Also, keep in mind that once you decide on which path you want to follow. You should go and consult a teacher/guru on that path.
My best wishes to you on this path.